# filling a column when empty with values powershell

Tags: powershell

I have recently added a new metadata field to my base content type called ‘mark’. This is a managed metadata column which should default to the term ‘off’.

As I have added this to the base content type, the field appears in the properties for most of our documents. the mark property field remains blank for ones created before the column was created.

Would it be possible to run a PowerShell to ensure that all documents with the field, detail ‘off’ in the column?? or is this possible in sharepoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Default Value of your Managed Metadata Column.

In powershell you can set as:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/02/15/updating-sharepoint-managed-metadata-columns-with-powershell.aspx

In C# you can set as

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21181.sharepoint-2010-setting-default-value-of-managed-metadata-column-for-a-completely-new-site-collection.aspx